# Recursive select that selects rows based own plus childrens values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select rows in a table like this:

[image: table a]

Select all rows in the table where both conditions are met:

- Condition 1: the value column should not match with any value in table v
- Condition 2: no decendent (on any level, ie: child or sub child, sub- sub- child etc) has a value that matches with any value in table v

Table v looks like this:

[image: table v]

Expected result from example table. Should [row] be selected/returned?

- a1: No - condition 2
- a2: No - condition 2
- a3: No - condition 1
- a4: No - condition 1
- a5: Yes - (value does not match in v and no decendents that match in v)
- a6: Yes - (value does not match in v and no decendents that match in v)
- a7: Yes - (value does not match in v and no decendents that match in v)
- a8: Yes - (value does not match in v and no decendents that match in v)

Here is an sqlfiddle where the tables are set up together with a recursive function that shows all rows and their level in the tree, but that I don't know how to procede with:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/736a28/15/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
--------------------------- DDL+DML
drop table if exists a
drop table if exists v
GO

CREATE TABLE a
    ([id] varchar(13), [parentId] varchar(57), [value] varchar(57))
;

CREATE TABLE v
    ([id] varchar(13), [value] varchar(57))
;

INSERT INTO a
    ([id], [parentId], [value])
VALUES
    ('a1', NULL, NULL),
    ('a2', 'a1', NULL),
    ('a3', 'a2', '1'),
    ('a4', NULL, '5'),
    ('a5', 'a1', '8'),
    ('a6', 'a2', NULL),
    ('a7', NULL, NULL),
    ('a8', NULL, '3'),
    ('a9', 'a8', '7')
;

INSERT INTO v
    ([id], [value])
VALUES
    ('v1', '1'),
    ('v2', '5'),
    ('v3', '10'),
    ('v4', '15'),
    ('v5', '20'),
    ('v6', '25'),
    ('v7', '30'),
    ('v8', '35'),
    ('v9', '40')
;

SELECT * FROM a
SELECT * FROM v
GO

-------------------- Solution

WITH MyRecCTE AS(
    SELECT a.id, a.parentId, a.[value], Res = 'NO'
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN v ON a.[value] = v.[value]
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        a.id, a.parentId, a.[value], Res = 'NO'
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN MyRecCTE c ON c.parentId = a.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.parentId,a.[value], ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),c.Res),'YES')
FROM a
LEFT JOIN MyRecCTE c ON a.id = c.id
ORDER BY id
GO
```

### Result Set (fits requested)):

[image]

For the sake of the discussion let's add another row which lead rows with id a8 and a9 to be "NO" since it is child of a9 and has value from the second table

```
INSERT INTO a
    ([id], [parentId], [value])
VALUES
    ('a10', 'a9', 35)
GO
```

### test 2 Result set (fits expected)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks nice! 

I have a limited understanding of the recurisive CTE: as I understand it you set all the values that match with v's values as anchors for the recursive part (and set a 'NO' to them) and then in the second part you iterate upwards - what makes it go upwards? I fail to see the difference from my example (where the anchor is on the top and iterates downwards with the same code).

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I did `:-)`. "what makes it go upwards?" : using `c.parentId = a.id` the parentid from the previous step should be like the id from the table in order to find the next step. " I fail to see the difference from my example" : The anchor rows is exactly the different. I am not trying to get all the rows in the table according to their hierarchy but only focus on these that should be "NO". the rest of the rows I get from the original table and not as part of the recursive.

Comment: Note that we speak about father-children hierarchy, which mean that each row can have only one father. Therefore, when you go down in the hierarchy as in your query, then each row which already being selected will not be selected again. Therefore, we do not need DISTINCT. But using this solution, we must use DISTICT since we are going from the anchor which is not all top level fathers, which mean that rows might come in the next iteration of the loop again - therefore we must add DISTINCT to fitter duplicate rows at the end

Answer (score 0):

This got somewhat complicated, but I created a CTE where there is a record that contains a `Path` for every combination of ancestor and descendant (transitive closure). Then, I create a second CTE where I extract the parent id from the beginning of `Path` and the descendant id from the end of `Path` and look up the descendant's value. Then, finally, I query the second CTE and use `NOT EXISTS` to filter the rows.

```
 WITH tree
    AS 
    ( 
  
        SELECT a.id, a.parentId, a.value,
                CAST('/' + a.id as varchar(1000)) as Path
        FROM a 
      
        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.id, a.parentId, a.value,
                CAST(t.Path + '/' + a.id as varchar(1000)) as Path
        FROM a
        INNER JOIN tree t
            ON Path LIKE '%/' + a.parentId
    ),
    DT
      AS
      (
        SELECT t.Path,
          RIGHT(LEFT(t.Path,3),2) as parent_id,
          RIGHT(t.Path,2) as descendant_id,
          (SELECT q.[value]
           FROM a q
           WHERE q.id = RIGHT(t.Path,2)
          ) as [descendant_value]

        FROM tree t
      )
   SELECT *
   FROM DT dt_outer
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DT dt_inner WHERE dt_inner.parent_id = dt_outer.parent_id AND
     dt_inner.descendant_value IN (SELECT [value] FROM v))
   ORDER BY 2,3
```

I left the result set with duplicates to get a clearer picture of what's going on. You can finish up with a `DISTINCT parent_id` to get the unique ids.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/736a28/48/0)

Comment: No need for the path. The trick which I used is not to start with the top level rows (these who have no parent in the table a. Instead I start with the last level - all the rows in table a which has a value in table v. Next I go up the hierarchy from the child to it's parent instead of down, in the opposite direction in the hierarchy. At the end I get all the rows which are "NO" and final step is to take all rows and JOIN the CTE with the rows that has "NO". I hope this poor explanation is clear. If not the query should explain better.

Comment: By the way, @neal-burns check your result set when you add the addition row which I added in my solution.

Comment: I do not succeed to create a reference to your name in the comment `:-)`. Not sure how it works when there are spaces...

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is elegant. I kind of brute-forced the recursive CTE because I don't have much experience with those.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the addition row...?

Comment: Hi, "I don't know what you mean by the addition row" : In my answer I added another row to the table `INSERT INTO a ([id], [parentId], [value]) VALUES ('a10', 'a9', 35) GO`. I meant to recommend that you will test your solution after you add this row. **Thanks for the nice feedback**

Comment: Oh.. you are saying it doesn't work for 3-digit ids? That's true.